Jump to STM32 application from Rust bootloader
I have a bootloader written in Rust (using cortex-m and embassy-stm32), and I need to jump to user application that's compiled in STM32CubeIDE and loaded at an offset (address 0x08080200). The bootloader performs the jump with this code:
unsafe fn jump_to(addr: u32) -> ! {
    cortex_m::interrupt::disable();

    let peri = cortex_m::Peripherals::steal();
    peri.SCB.vtor.write(addr);

    cortex_m::asm::bootload(addr as *const u32);
}

// Later

jump_to(0x0808_0200)

When the application compiled in STM32CubeIDE is flashed to address 0x08080200 (via ST-Link) and the bootloader is about to jump, the device seems to reset (LEDs turn off and probe-rs doesn't complain), but then nothing happens - no LED turns on (not even one corresponding to HardFault) and I don't get a signal about CPU being locked up.
I have made sure the user application is linked with FLASH : ORIGIN = 0x08080200, and that SCB->VTOR = 0x08080200. I looked into the binaries and everything seems fine.
When I try to jump from my bootloader to a toy application written in Rust, it works. When I try to jump to the STM32 application from a toy bootloader written in C and compiled by STM32, it works.
I suspect that I'm not resetting some registers properly (in STM32, one does HAL_DeInit()). However, I don't know how to do that properly (the crate doesn't provide a deinit function), and the issue might still be elsewhere.
I also tried building a barebones bootloader in Rust that just jumps to 0x0808_0200, but it doesn't work either.
Minimal Reproducible Example:
Get a board with STM32F767VGTx chip.
Setup a Rust project with following files:
.cargo/config.toml:
[target.'cfg(all(target_arch = "arm", target_os = "none"))']
runner = "probe-rs run --chip STM32F767VGTx --connect-under-reset"

linker = "flip-link"

[build]
target = "thumbv7em-none-eabihf"

Cargo.toml:
// ...

[dependencies]
cortex-m = "0.7.7"
cortex-m-rt = "0.7.3"
panic-halt = "0.2.0"

src/main.rs:
#![no_std]
#![no_main]

// Panic handler
//
use panic_halt as _;

#[cortex_m_rt::entry]
fn main() -> ! {
    unsafe { jump_to(0x0808_0200) }
}

unsafe fn jump_to(addr: u32) -> ! {
    cortex_m::interrupt::disable();

    let peri = cortex_m::Peripherals::steal();
    peri.SCB.vtor.write(addr);

    cortex_m::asm::bootload(addr as *const u32);
}

Setup an STM32 project (use STM32CubeMX to generate the code for the corresponding board, add watchdog and LWIP as compunents). I'm not going to list all the code here (it's quite bloated), but here's the main function:
int main(void)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN 1 */

  /* USER CODE END 1 */

  /* MCU Configuration--------------------------------------------------------*/

  /* Reset of all peripherals, Initializes the Flash interface and the Systick. */
  HAL_Init();

  /* USER CODE BEGIN Init */

  /* USER CODE END Init */

  /* Configure the system clock */
  SystemClock_Config();

  /* USER CODE BEGIN SysInit */
  /* USER CODE END SysInit */

  /* Initialize all configured peripherals */
  MX_GPIO_Init();
  MX_SDMMC1_SD_Init();
  MX_LWIP_Init();
  MX_IWDG_Init();
  /* USER CODE BEGIN 2 */

  unsigned tmo = HAL_GetTick();
  const unsigned TMO = 500;

  /* USER CODE END 2 */

  /* Infinite loop */
  /* USER CODE BEGIN WHILE */
    while (1)
    {
        HAL_IWDG_Refresh(&hiwdg);

        if (HAL_GetTick() - tmo >= TMO)
        {
            tmo = HAL_GetTick();
            HAL_GPIO_TogglePin(LED_ETH_GPIO_Port, LED_ETH_Pin);
        }

        MX_LWIP_Process();
    /* USER CODE END WHILE */

    /* USER CODE BEGIN 3 */
    }
    Error_Handler();
  /* USER CODE END 3 */
}

... and a part of the linker script:
/* ... */

MEMORY
{
    RAM (xrw)  : ORIGIN = 0x20000000, LENGTH = 512K
    FLASH (RX) : ORIGIN = 0x08080200, LENGTH = 1024K - 0x80200
}

/* ... */


Edited. However, the main issue is that I don't really have a well-defined problem description. Everything seems to be alright - no faults, no lock-ups, even the network stack of user application seems to be set-up - but then the main loop doesn't get executed (LEDs don't blink). This also seems to just be a problem for the combination Rust->C, not C->C nor C->Rust (bootloader->application).
